# How to display the column names vertically in Google colab?

Tags: python, pandas, output, google-colaboratory, settings

In google colab, my df.columns used to display column names vertically like below

```py
Index(['col1',

       'col2',

       'col3'],

dtype='object')
```

I was trying different pandas setup options like

- pd.set_option('display.max_row',100),
- pd.set_option('display.max_columns',100), width, etc. for another issue.

Now, df.columns displays like this:

```py
Index(['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], dtype='object')
```

I tried deleting the options, resetting its width, but couldn't fix it.
How do I get back to display the columns vertically?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pprint 
columns = df.index

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4, width=1)
pprint.pprint(columns)
```